# VS 2019 C++ CLR/CLI совместимость со старыми Windows

Tags: c++, совместимость

Можно ли сделать программу,написанную в VS2019(C++ CLR/CLI с использованием форм) совместимой со старыми Windows или со старыми версиями VS? Получается так,что я пишу код на Win10,а запускать программу нужно на компьютерах университета с Win XP или Win Vista(как повезет). Запустить уже скомпилированную программу не получается,всегда получаю какую-то ошибку(в основном отсутствует какой-то dll). Открыть код в установленной на тех компьютерах VS2008 тоже не выходит из-за проблем совместимости. Есть ли решение этой проблемы,кроме как сохранять код в блокноте и копировать в старую студию?